# Getting Yosemite instead of El Capitan

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, recovery

I purchased a Macbook Air 10.11.2 El Capitan back in February 2016. I didn't install any upgrades because I'm satisfied with El Capitan.

When I started having problems earlier this year (2017), I decided to make a clean reinstall of El Capitan.  The only option left for me was to download it through Internet recovery so I waited until it finished downloading.

After downloading, it came up with the Recovery mode.  I erased the Mac partition and reinstalled OSX.  It appears to be different, instead of having El Capitan it gives me the Yosemite version.  That's unacceptable to me.  I purchased my mac that came with El Capitan but the downloaded version is Yosemite (which I think I was scammed by the store seller).

Is this something normal or something I have to complain about back to the store?  Also, Yosemite is giving me an error upon entering my Apple ID, it says that the item is temporarily unavailable.

What should I do now?  I need help,  and I would appreciate it much.  Thanks!

Comment: If you have never downloaded El Capitan before and the answer below doesn't work, but you have an Apple Store nearby, set a Genius Bar appointment. Apple will re-install the OS free of charge in their stores.

Comment: Where did you buy the MacBook?

Answer (score 2):

I think You should make clean install of El Capitan from USB. You were not scammed, don't worry. I was in the same situation.
**It can be done under one condition - You've updated somewhere in the past to the El Capitan and You can see it in Purchased section in AppStore.**
That's nothing complicated, first make sure that You have downloaded El Capitan from AppStore. Than You should make bootable El Capitan USB and clean-install it on Your Mac. Follow these steps on this site:

http://www.macworld.com/article/2981585/operating-systems/how-to-make-a-bootable-os-x-10-11-el-capitan-installer-drive.html

Comment: I assumed that user has downloaded El Capitan in the past, and yes El Capitan can be downloaded **only** if You've downloaded/"purchased" it once.